# Binomial identity for $4^k$ using previous results and sums

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I have the following equation from [a previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299421/finding-binomial-expansion-of-a-radical):
\begin{equation}
\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\right) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty{2k\choose k}x^k
\end{equation}

I want to square the equation:

\begin{equation} 
\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\right)^2=\left(\dfrac{1}{{1-4x}}\right)=\left[\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^k{k\choose i}^2\right)x^k\right]^2
\end{equation}
From calculus we know this is equals:
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty4^kx^k
\end{equation}

Now, I would like to find a binomial identity for $4^k$. How can I do this with the above?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: I think, you missed $(-1)^k$ somewhere. Decomposition of inverse powers should have sign changing somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coefficient of $x^k$ in

$$\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{2k}kx^k\right)^2$$

is

$$\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{2i}i\binom{2k-2i}{k-i}\;,$$

so you get the binomial identity

$$\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{2i}i\binom{2k-2i}{k-i}=4^k\;.$$