# Expansion of generating function $\frac{1}{ \sqrt{1-12x+4x^2 } }$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions

I came across this generating function

$$\frac{1}{ \sqrt{1-12x+4x^2 } }$$

How exactly does one expand this series? I have read through some notes, it seems like we need to factorize the denominator, but it doesn't look like this one can be factorized?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A084773

Comment: It's easy to consider this function as $g(x) = (1 - 12x + 4x^2)^{-1/2}$. Then you should consider Taylor expansion of this function. But maybe it will be really difficult to calculate.

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks, but I am more curious technically how do you expand this generating function

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with this series? I mean, one thing you can do is use the Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{ \sqrt{1-x } }$ and then replace $x$ by $(12x-4x^2)$. FOIL out couple of terms. If you are willing to spend a little time, you can work out up till fourth power and combine like terms. Then you would have essentially five terms (constant up till the $x^4$ term). Just an idea

Comment: @imranfat hmm I just want to study the rules of operations on generating functions. But I guess not all generating function can be expanded elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [generalized Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem),

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y}} =1-\frac{1}{2}y+\frac{3}{8}y^2-\frac{5}{16}y^3+\frac{35}{128}y^4-\frac{63}{256}y^5+\dots 
$$

Substitute $y=4x^2-12x$, expand and gather terms to get

$$
\frac{1}{ \sqrt{1-12x+4x^2 } }=1+6 x+52 x^2+504 x^3+5136 x^4+53856 x^5+\dots
$$

Aside: a commenter pointed out that the coefficients of this series form a sequence with various interpretations: https://oeis.org/A084773.

Comment: I guess the main problem deals with expanding $(4x^2 - 12x)^k$ terms.

Comment: @openspace. Binomial theorem again ! There is another way to do it by identification.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-12x+4x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2tz+t^2}} \implies t=2x, z=3$$
Recall the generating function for the Legendre Polynomials:
$$(1-2zt+t^2)^{-1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n(z) t^n, ~if~ |t|<min [z \pm \sqrt{z^2-1}]$$
And
$$(1-2zt+t^2)^{-1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n(z) t^{-(n+1)}, ~if~ |t|> max [z \pm \sqrt{z^2-1}]$$
So $$f(x)=\sum P_n(3)~ 2^n ~x^n, ~if~ |x| <3-2\sqrt{2}$$
And
$$f(x)=\sum P_n(3)~ 2^{-(n+1)} ~x^{-(n+1)}, ~if~ |x| >3+2\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Make the long division

$$\frac{1}{ 1-12x+4x^2  }=1+12 x+140 x^2+1632 x^3+19024 x^4+221760 x^5+2585024 x^6+O\left(x^7\right)$$

Now (being patient), the binomial expansion
$$\frac{1}{ \sqrt{1-12x+4x^2 } }=1+6 x+52 x^2+504 x^3+5136 x^4+53856 x^5+575296 x^6+O\left(x^7\right)$$

Comment: Could you add just a little more detail on how binomial expansion leads from the first series to the second? I don't see it. A link would be fine.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299421 and/or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem